# Fastlane finds wrong certificate when multiply is installed on CI Machine

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, provisioning-profile, fastlane

Simply I have 2 lanes in *AppFile*:

```
for_lane :app_dev do
  apple_id "email@email1.com"
  team_id "KLMNOPGRST"
end

for_lane :app_prod do
  apple_id "email@email2.com"
  team_id "ABCDEFGHIJ"
end
```

And for team_id `ABCDEFGHIJ` there is certificate **BCERT** and for team_id `KLMNOPGRST` there is **ACERT** certificate. Both of them are installed on CI machine... but for the first lane `app_test` CI founds certificate BCERT instead of ACERT. Why?

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|                          Summary for cert 2.180.1                           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| api_key                 | ********                                          |
| development             | false                                             |
| force                   | false                                             |
| generate_apple_certs    | true                                              |
| username                | email@email1.com                              |
| team_id                 | KLMNOPGRST                                        |
| keychain_path           | /Users/me/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db |
| skip_set_partition_list | false                                             |
| platform                | ios                                               |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+

[11:29:00]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
[11:29:01]: Found the certificate 56JF6H2Y6G (BCERT) which is installed on the local machine. Using this one.
[11:29:01]: Verifying the certificate is properly installed locally...
[11:29:01]: Successfully installed certificate 56JF6H2Y6G
[11:29:01]: Use signing certificate '56JF6H2Y6G' from now on!
[11:29:01]: ------------------
[11:29:01]: --- Step: sigh ---
[11:29:01]: ------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure you registered the identifier `"email@email1.com"` in the right account?